# How to pass "const asserted" variables to functions that accept less strict arguments

Tags: typescript

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDaByAhhgNDDAIzwOBIwBMMBdGLCGUSKAbhgHp2YAbEKBkHBgALLACcKoCgFMKMaGICWYAOYQAUOu7TYhcQC4YUAJ4AHaYPiI0YAK4BbQtLG1URDGw5cT5mCtvicnpiMAC0RsKKDFEwAO7CxjAAkjAgprBQSLYQ0jAARPSM4NB5RkhOKspxilDCmnC2YMBQiuDwYAAU4mKGCsoqaNQAlDAA3uowk0WQINoAdLwqXWJiQ+oAvvWdCCBDbJwwzmIgPVZIMYr29rZQWITaMIQ3dCswMde399LqcNuIdAw+qpBnsvHRuBAkEcToZjCBbIwsGAMLAmAA3ZywODHexvK43O4PTIwD6E3I-TpoObUnbDfbeSIMWInADWEHwT1gomALOMQA)

```
const foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as const; // lots of hardcoded strings

let bar: typeof foo[number] = 'b';  // type guard bar - this is why I opt to use "as const" to begin with

function fn(arr: string[]) {
  console.log(arr)
}

fn(foo); // error: foo is immutable but arr is mutable
fn(foo as string[]); // also error: you can't convert from immutable to mutable
```

How can I pass `foo` to to `fn` as argument? One solution is `fn([...foo])`, but I wonder if there's a less hacky way.

Comment: With as const you told the compiler the array must not be mutated. But passing it to a function that accepts a regular array means it could be mutated in that function, which has no such limitation on the value it receives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `fn` should accept `readonly string[]` as parameter. If you can not make changes to the function, the safest way is `fn([...foo])` because you do not want the `fn` function to mutate your array. If you are really sure that the function do not modify your array: `fn(foo as unknown as string[])`

Answer (score 1):

```
function fn(arr: readonly string[]) {
    console.log(arr)
}
```